# How to make a git orphan branch with last three commits?

Tags: git

I want to make a orphan branch with only last three commits history?

```
MASTER -> A - B - C - D - E - F 
NEW ORPHAN -> D - E -F
```

This is for, I want to retain the new orphan branch and delete the existing branch to use less disk space.

Comment: The purpose is _saving disk space?_ What do you have in that history (like, an accidentally committed Ubuntu ISO or something)? Also, have you tried `git gc`?

Comment: No, I want to automate backing up of a large file to a git repo. So that I can have recent backups while deleting the old ones

Comment: If you have only the last 3 commits, you'll lose whatever information was introduced in the first three and not subsequently changed. Or should new `D` incorporate `A..C` ?

Comment: @Useless so I'll not have the whole file, if I lose A...C?

Comment: @AH - No, that's incorrect.  Useless is falling into the common misconception that git commits record changes, which is false.

Comment: The whole thing is to store my mysql backups to bitbucket without exceeding their 2GB limit by removing the old commits.

Comment: Is your database growing with time? (This has [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) written all over it.)

Comment: Yeah, I get change about 45mb per commit. I push about 12 times in a day

Comment: Well, you lose the information about where that data came from, because you're effectively making `D` the new initial commit. And yes, using a VCS for backup seems weird.

Answer (score 3):

The truth is, git probably isn't the solution for the problem you present.  It's not great at handling large files, and getting it to actually release the disk space from a removed commit is rather difficult (because it *is* great at retaining history).  So the most useful answer is: don't.

But I'll also offer the more technically complete answers.

If your intent is to discard the older commits, then there's really no need to go with an orphan branch.  You can rebase the branch you have.  The easiest way is an interactive rebase

```
git rebase -i
```

A TODO list will pop up with an entry for each commit.  Find the entries for `B`, `C`, and `D` and change the first word (the command) for those entries from `pick` to `squash`.

You will be left with

```
A -- B -- C -- D -- E -- F

ABCD -- E' -- F' <--(master)
```

whose content (`TREE`) of `ABCD`, `E'`, and `F'` match those from the original `D`, `E`, and `F` respectively.  This is the same state you would work toward (with more hoops to go through) by using an orphan branch.

In particular, note that even though they're unreachable by any ref, the original commits `A` through `F` still exist.  Given enough time, they would be reclaimed.  First they would have to roll off the reflog (or you would have to destroy the reflog).  Then `git gc` would have to run.

One quick(ish) way around that is to create a new clone after the rebase.

Of course, interactive rebase isn't the easiest thing to script, so if you are wanting a repeatable procedure you might have to do something a little different.  You could write a script something like

```
# get the work tree for a new root
git checkout master~2
# break from history
git checkout --orphan new_master
# start the new branch
git commit -C master~2
git rebase --onto new_master master~2 master
git branch -d new_master
```

You still have the problem that the old commits are hanging around in the database continuing to consume space.

Yet another option is to use "shallow branches".  As far as I know shallow branches are created only by cloning, but on the plus side that takes care of purging the old objects from the database.  This also preserves the commit metadata (and commit identities).

```
git clone --depth=3 --no-single-branch file://localhost/path/to/old/repo new-repo
```

Do note that the `depth` option only sets the *initial* depth in the repo.  You'd still have to "re-shallow" the repo periodically.